# Substring and Join in Twig

Tags: twig, substring

I know it's possible to join an array in twig, like so:

```
['name_first', 'name_second', 'name_third']|join(', ')
{# name_first, name_second, name_third #}
```

I also know I can use `[5:]` to remove the 'name_' part of each element. But, is it possible combine both, without looping over the whole thing. So, the final result will be:

```
first, second, third
```

Comment: `{{ ['name_first', 'name_second', 'name_third']|join(',')|replace({'name_':'',}) }}`?

Comment: Exactly! With your inspiration... `{{ ['name_first', 'name_second', 'name_third']|join(',')[5:] }}`
Post as answer. /cc @DarkBee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inspiration from DarkBee's comment, it's pretty easy to achieve.

```
{{ ['name_first', 'name_second', 'name_third']|join(',')[5:] }}
```

This removes the first 5 characters of each member of the array then concatenates them with a comma separating them.